# How do I get the Web Directory during Application_Start?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express

I am trying to read a file during Application_Start from my web application.

However at the Application_Start I am unable to get the file published to the Web Directory.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("settings.json"))
    {

    }
}
```

The file was added to the web project, and set to Copy to Output Folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Using the MapPath method returns the actual file-system path to the root of your site.

Comment: Thanks I didnt think I could use MapPath before the Request started :D